# I could participate in the music show

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence, please:

a) *If I had been serious about music when I was young, today I **could participate** in the music show.*

Is sentence a) correct or do we have to use "***could have participated***" instead? In other words, do we use the following construction in English?

IF+SUBJECT+**HAD**+**PP**, SUBJECT+ **COULD/MIGHT/WOULD**+**BARE INFINITIVE**.

Comment: You must use "could have participated"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence in the question—it's quite correct. So too would be versions with *might* and *would*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I could have participated" is okay but strictly speaking it applies after the event. You need "would" to indicate the future.

If I had practised when I was young, I could have participated in yesterday's concert.

If I had practised when I was young, I would have been able to participate in tomorrow's concert.

If the concert is today then which you use depends on whether the concert has already happened or is yet to happen.

---

Note that many native speakers don't think this hard about the words they use so you might hear all sorts of variations.

Comment: *If I had learnt music when I was young, I **would participate** in today's concert*.(statement made before the concert starts)---Is the sentence correct?

Comment: No. However the reasons aren't simple. "would" is the simple past of "will".  The verb "will" has two senses, one being *having the will to do something* and the other as an auxiliary verb indicating the future. Strictly speaking, English has no future tense.That makes "would" complicated. It contains elements of future, past, and having the will to do something! I don't think I can fit a full explanation into a comment!

Comment: Google Books... [*could have gone tomorrow*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22could+have+gone+tomorrow%22&oq=%22could+have+gone+tomorrow%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l4.12407j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): about 48,400 results, [would have been able to go tomorrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would+have+been+able+to+go+tomorrow%22&oq=%22would+have+been+able+to+go+tomorrow%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10946j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): 4 results. I'll grant it's possible to "justify" the latter, but I don't think that's anywhere near the same as saying that "strictly speaking" it's "more correct".

Comment: (Even more "syntactically precise": [*would have been able to have gone tomorrow*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would+have+been+able+to+have+gone+tomorrow%22&oq=%22would+have+been+able+to+have+gone+tomorrow%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.8527j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which gets no hits at all! :)

Comment: @ FumbleFingers - An interesting point: It just sits uneasily on my ear. I think it depends on the  context and maybe I should give it some more thought. I admit my remark was somewhat prescriptive though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, *(Even more "syntactically precise": **would have been able to have gone tomorrow***. Can we use it with yesterday or any other past time? For example: "*would have been able to have gone yesterday*"??

Comment: @Mr. X - I think that FumbleFingers is joking: indicating that such precision is overkill. It is not a suggestion for actual use, it is a subtle criticism of my answer.

Comment: [*If my aunt had balls, she'd be my uncle.*](https://www.phrases.com/phrase/if-my-aunt-had-balls,-she'd-be-my-uncle_8624) You'll never hear *...she **would have been** my uncle* there. All I'm saying is there's quite a pronounced tendency in English to use "simpler" tenses in many contexts where pedantry and/or logic might either "justify" or "require" more complex forms.